# Making a program with 3 buttons. Text input to change the case before output into a p.How to proceed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is for a project I'm working on, and the reading materials been provided are not making sense here when it comes to helping me. I have to have a function defined per button and an additional function to change the contents of the paragraph element to the final text. Here's my HTML and Javascript code. What I'm not quite understanding is how the returns from the functions need to communicate to the final function that will output the changed text to the paragraph element. When I run the program, I am prompted for an input, but after that, nothing happens. Please help me understand the concepts I am missing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>String Methods</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="brimberry_pr9.css">
        </head>

        <body>
            <div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="brimberry_pr9.js"></script>
                <button id="uppercase" onclick="uppercase()";>UPPERCASE</button>
                <br>
                <button id="lowercase" onclick="lowercase()";>lowercase</button>
                <br>
                <button id="capitalFirst" onclick="capitalFirst()";>Capital First</button>
            </div>
            <p id="output">Your Changed Text Will Appear Here</p>

        </body>
    </html>
```

```html
    function uppercase() {
     getInput = prompt("Enter some text below.");
     upperChange = getInput.toUpperCase();
     return upperChange;
    }
    function lowercase() {
     getInput = prompt("Enter some text below.");
     lowerChange = getInput.toLowerCase();
     return lowerChange;
    }
    function capitalFirst() {
     getInput = prompt("Enter some text below.");
     firstChange = getInput.toLowerCase();
     capitalizeChange = firstChange.toUpperCase(0);
     return capitalizeChange;
    }
    function setToParagraph() {
     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = upperChange;
     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = lowerChange;
     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = capitalizeChange;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return anything from three functions. You need to call the function which changes the paragraph value with the text that you have modified. I have made changes to the function capitalFirst.

```
        function uppercase() {
        getInput = prompt("Enter some text below.");
        upperChange = getInput.toUpperCase();
        setToParagraph(upperChange);
    }
    function lowercase() {
        getInput = prompt("Enter some text below.");
        lowerChange = getInput.toLowerCase();
        setToParagraph(lowerChange);
    }
    function capitalFirst() {
        getInput = prompt("Enter some text below.");
        firstChange = getInput.toLowerCase();
        capitalizeChange = firstChange.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + firstChange.slice(1);
        setToParagraph(capitalizeChange);
    }
    function setToParagraph(p) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = p;  
    }
```